# How to pivot columns and update the pivoted data afterwards

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
GLLink int
Budget01 float
Budget02 float
Budget03 float
Budget04 float
Budget05 float
Budget06 float
Budget07 float
...
Budget57 float
Budget58 float
Budget59 float
Budget60 float
```

For each column, there is 8 rows because of my filter.

All of these columns has values.

I need to set each columns value to zero, however I have the understanding that I would need to pivot the data and then update afterwards?

I know you can just `transpose` the results in Excel and then develop you query in Excel, however, I would like to know how to achieve this without using Excel.

After the transpose in Excel, my update query would look like this:

```
update Budgets set Budget01 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget02 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget03 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget04 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget05 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget06 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget07 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
...
update Budgets set Budget57 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget58 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget59 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
update Budgets set Budget60 = 0 where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
```

How would I need to develop the same update query in SQL, without using Excel and taking all of the above in consideration?

Comment: How have you reached the point of having 60 identically named columns and *not* realised that there's something not quite right here? It sounds like you should have a table with 3 columns - `GLLink`, `Budget`, and one for whatever *data* the numbers 1-60 represent that is instead currently embedded into your column names.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes, all the column names are identical, except for the number. So are you suggesting that I use a temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the One Update To Rule Them All

```
update Budgets 
set 
Budget01 = 0,
Budget02 = 0,  
Budget03 = 0,  
...
Budget59 = 0,
Budget60 = 0
where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like '3200>%')
```

Or use Dynamic SQL

**Example:**

```
declare @Cols NVARCHAR(max);
declare @DynSql NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT @Cols = concat(@Cols+', ',char(10), Col.Name, '=0')
FROM SYS.OBJECTS Obj
JOIN SYS.COLUMNS Col ON Obj.OBJECT_ID = Col.OBJECT_ID
WHERE Obj.TYPE='U' 
  AND Obj.NAME = 'Budgets'
  AND Col.Name LIKE 'Budget[0-9][0-9]';

set @DynSql = N'update Budgets set '+ @Cols + char(10) +
'where GLLink in (select AccountLink from Accounts where Master_Sub_Account like ''3200>%'')';

exec(@DynSql);
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dadf81432a5c0c3dfd5d1ab68bda8bfe)*